# JavaFX: Getting GridPane cell to the desired vertical position

Tags: javafx

My desired behavior below is for `fieldPane` to be vertically centered next to `table`, but the two are top-aligned (in `bigGrid` row 0).  Why is this happening?  How should I do this?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {


        TableView table = new TableView();

        GridPane fieldPane = new GridPane();
        Button addButton = new Button("Add Crew"), 
                updateButton = new Button("Update Crew");
        Label crewIdLabel = new Label("Crew ID"),
                crewNameLabel = new Label("Crew Name");
        TextField crewIdText = new TextField(),
                crewNameText = new TextField();
        fieldPane.setHgap(10);
        fieldPane.setVgap(10);
        fieldPane.addRow(0, crewIdLabel, crewIdText);
        fieldPane.addRow(1, crewNameLabel, crewNameText);

        GridPane bigPane = new GridPane();
        bigPane.setHgap(10);
        bigPane.setVgap(10);
        bigPane.add(table, 0, 0, 2, 1);
        bigPane.add(fieldPane, 2, 0, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(fieldPane, VPos.CENTER);
        bigPane.add(addButton, 1, 1, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(addButton, HPos.RIGHT);
        bigPane.add(updateButton, 3, 1, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setHalignment(updateButton, HPos.RIGHT);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bigPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you modify this code so that it creates a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fieldPane` is filling the entire contents of its cell in `bigPane`, as you can check by putting a border on it. Since there is additional space inside the `fieldPane`, beyond that needed to hold its content, the cells in the `fieldPane` need to be positioned within that extra space. The default alignment is top left; to change it you can do

```
fieldPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

Alternatively, you can prevent the `fieldPane` from growing to fill its entire cell with

```
GridPane.setFillHeight(fieldPane, false);
```

and then because you already have

```
GridPane.setValignment(fieldPane, VPos.CENTER);
```

the `fieldPane` will be centered in its grid cell.

Comment: I added those lines right after the 'big grid pane' section, and it does not appear to have had an effect.